# How to upload pictures in custom folders in WordPress

Tags: php, upload, wordpress

I have a specific situation:

I need to upload pictures in WordPress, but I can't store them all in wp-content/uploads

I need,etc. to have 3 folders:

wp-content/uploads/folder1
wp-content/uploads/folder2
wp-content/uploads/folder3

And then,when uploading pictures, to can choose in which folder to be stored..

I try a couple plug-ins, but no result.

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your **wp-config**

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads/folder1');
```

Make sure you add this code before the line - the above line

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
```

Comment: Can I made three folders like this and made custom update ? I don't think so... I try,don't work